# How to specify a variadic (ellipsis) parameter as optional in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, optional-parameters, variadic-functions

Is it possible to have a variadic parameter be optional in Swift?  I tried the two ways that made sense and neither compile:

```
func myFunc(queryFormat: String?...) {

}
```

or

```
func myFunc(queryFormat: String...?) {

}
```

Note: The 1st implementation technically compiles but if you try to unwrap it:

```
if let queryFormatUnwrapped = queryFormat {
...
}
```

You get an error `Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional Type` which indicates to me its treating it as an Array of optional Strings not an optional Array of Strings (which is kind of silly).

Comment: Would you just check if the array was empty?

Comment: @ABakerSmith If I try to unwrap `queryFormat`, it throws an error which indicates that its treating it as an array of optional strings not an optional array of strings.

Comment: As @Tobias suggests, there is no way to make the _entire parameter pack_ optional.  What would that mean?  The user can supply zero or more arguments, that arrive in an array.  How/why would that array be optional?  On the other hand, the parameters _themselves_ can be optional.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's not possible to have a an optional variadic parameter.
The function will always receive an array for the variadic parameter.

However, the array can be empty, or the values in the array can be nil.

I threw some sample code together, hope it helps communicate what I'm trying to say.

```
func vardicPrint(strings: String...) {
    if strings.isEmpty {
        print("EMPTY")
    } else {
        for string in strings {
            print(string)
        }
    }
}

func optionalPrint(maybeStrings: String?...) {
    if maybeStrings.isEmpty {
        print("EMPTY")
    } else {
        for string in maybeStrings {
            if let string = string {
                print(string)
            } else {
                print("nil")
            }

        }
    }
}

vardicPrint("Hello", "World", "!")
vardicPrint()


var nilString: String?
optionalPrint("Goodbye", nilString, "World", "!")

/* OUTPUT:
Hello
World
!
EMPTY

Goodbye
nil
World
!
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

I would filter the nil values with compactMap like below:

```
func myFunc(queryFormat: String?...) {
    // queryFormat is now an optional-String array = [String?]

    let queryFormat = queryFormat.compactMap { $0 }
    // queryFormat is now a String array = [String]

    print(queryFormat)
}
```

This can be called as:

```
myFunc(queryFormat: nil)
myFunc(queryFormat: "format")
myFunc(queryFormat: "format1", "format2")
```

Output will be:

```
[]
["format"]
["format1", "format2"]
```